# React Native - Error using Chart Kit (Exception thrown while executing UI block: __NSCFNumber firstObject: unrecognized selector sent to instance)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

Im trying to run a basic React Native App using the Chart Kit library I get this error:
[CLICK FOR IMAGE: Exception thrown while executing UI block: __NSCFNumber firstObject: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa3576e305374b97e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emSzB.png)

Does someone know how to fix it?

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts';

class LineChartExample extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const data = [50, 10, 40, 95, -4, -24, 85, 91, 35, 53, -53, 24, 50, -20, -80];

    return (
        <LineChart
            style={{ height: 200 }}
            data={data}
            svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }}
            contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
        >
          <Grid />
        </LineChart>
    )
  }
}

export default LineChartExample;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I have solved a simillar problem here for Victory Native: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73302893/614065

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it!! I'm using Expo for my project and I used npm to install react-native-chart-kit and react-native-svg. For some reason using nmp I got the error but after uninstalling it and using "expo install", to install react-native-chart-kit again, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, but did not solved using "expo install install react-native-chart-kit"

the issue  continue

**Exception thrown while executing UI block: __NSCFNumber firstObject: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d7ca23b6657dd3d**

EDITING: I solved my issue, steps:

1 - use CMD aways... create your expo-project and all dependences and library using CMD prompt comand windows... **dont use PowerShell**

2 - install react-native-svg-charts, react-native-chart-kit, react-native-svg-charts,   **using "expo instal ...."** DON'T use *yarn add or npm install*

I hope this help everyone to create charts with expo....